# Определить что за БД

Tags: база-данных

Есть файл с расширением .dbd... Хочу узнать что это за база данных и как её правильно прочитать. Заголовок в hex - редакторе прилагаю.[image: заголовок]

Comment: А почему это вообще должно быть __базой данных__?

Comment: [What is a DBD file?](https://filext.com/file-extension/DBD)

Comment: EPICS DATABASES (DBD - это файл описания базы)

Answer (score 0):

> Выходной файл DemoShield проект приложение, используемое в качестве установки для демо программного обеспечения. Эти инсталляторы добавляются с .dbd расширения и хранятся в формате DBD. Программное обеспечение DemoShield является приложение, разработанное компанией Macrovision, чтобы обеспечить программистов с набором функциональных возможностей полезные в создании программ инсталляции для своих проектов приложений демо. Эти файлы DBD также используются в создании интерактивных презентаций с мультимедийными объектами. Характеристики сжатия, используемый в качестве стандартов для онлайн и оффлайн распределения контента реализованы в файл DBD. Интеграция программного обеспечения DemoShield и формат DBD в приложении InstallShield было сделано в 2007 году, за год до "Macrovision" было изменено на "Acresso программного обеспечения". 2007 год был также годом, когда разработка и поддержка были прекращены по программе DemoShield. Пользователи систем Microsoft Windows, основанных на можно установить версии приложения DemoShield для доступа к интегрированные функции для развития этих программ инсталляции и осуществлять поддержку в своих системах этих файлов DBD.

[Источник](https://www.reviversoft.com/ru/file-extensions/dbd)